# Creating Matrix in smalltalk in visualworks

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks

I am trying to put a value to particular location in 2D matrix in smalltalk(visualworks) with following code:

```
   xrow: rowIndex ycolumn: columnIndex put:aNumber
   |num|

   self at: (rowIndex*xrow+ columnIndex) put: aNumber.
```

and i am getting an unhandled exception  as:
        #productFromSmallInterger.

please help in this. 
thank you

Comment: Without more information it's hard to tell for sure, but it looks like either rowIndex or xrow are either nil or some other object.  Can you explain where xrow is initialized and what kind of object it contains?

Comment: Like David says, but your code might have other problems, like Smalltalk indices are 1-based, not 0-based, what about your rowIndex, columnIndex? If 1-based the formula should look like (rowIndex-1)*numberOfColumns + columnIndex. If xrow is a number of rows, then the formula sounds weird.